# Minimum rotation using Suffix array-- Revisited

Tags: string, algorithm, suffix-array

Consider a string of length n (1 <= n <= 100000). 
    Determine its minimum lexicographic rotation. 
    For example, the rotations of the string “alabala” are:

```
alabala

labalaa

abalaal

balaala

alaalab

laalaba

aalabal

and the smallest among them is “aalabal”.
```

This question has already been asked on Stack but I'm re asking it as no clear solution is available. Till now I made following progress.
1. Take S, concat with reverse(S)..let P=S+reverse(S)
2.construct suffix array of above string P

Now my question is if I pick first string in suffix array of `size> strlen(S)` then prefix of size `strlen(S)` of this string will be minimum rotation of given string S.

Is my conclusion correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, in general it is wrong (if I understand correctly what you mean).  Of course it works ok for your palindromic input.

See the following output from python interpreter, where input strings include `'alabala'` and `'alabatta'`.  (Output has had some spaces and linewraps added.)  In the second section, the front part of the first suffix longer than S is inadmissable, ie is not a rotation of S.  See third section for an approach that works.

```
>>> s = 'alabala'; p = s + ''.join(reversed(s))
>>> sorted([p[i:] for i in range(len(p))])
['a', 'aalabala', 'abala', 'abalaalabala', 'ala', 'alaalabala',
 'alabala', 'alabalaalabala', 'bala', 'balaalabala', 'la',
 'laalabala', 'labala', 'labalaalabala']

>>> s = 'alabatta'; p = s + ''.join(reversed(s))
>>> sorted([p[i:] for i in range(len(p))])
['a', 'aattabala', 'abala', 'abattaattabala', 'ala', 'alabattaattabala',
 'attaattabala', 'attabala', 'bala', 'battaattabala', 'la',
 'labattaattabala', 'taattabala', 'tabala', 'ttaattabala', 'ttabala']

>>> s = 'alabatta'; p = s + s
>>> sorted([p[i:] for i in range(len(p))])
['a', 'aalabatta', 'abatta', 'abattaalabatta', 'alabatta', 
 'alabattaalabatta', 'atta', 'attaalabatta', 'batta', 'battaalabatta',
 'labatta', 'labattaalabatta', 'ta', 'taalabatta', 'tta', 'ttaalabatta']
```